# Group of order $p^2$ has at most $p+1$ subgroups of order $p$

Tags: group-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number and $G$ a group of order $p^2$, then $G$ has at most $p + 1$ subgroups of order $p$. Give an example where the quota $p + 1$ is reached and an example where the quota is not reached.

Simplifying a lot, my solution is

Let $H_1$, ..., $H_n$ be $n$ distinct subgroups of G of order $p$, $|H_i|=p$ means $H_i$ is cyclic, thus $H_i \cap H_j = \{e\}$ for $i \ne j$.

Then $|H_1 \cup... \cup H_n|=n(p-1)+1 \le p^2 = |G|$.

But I don't know which example leads to $n=p+1$. The other one I used $\mathbb Z_4$ ($n=1$).

Comment: A two-dimensional vectors space over $\Bbb{Z}_p$ has ____ one-dimensional subspaces.

Comment: Sorry I'm not really good at linear algebra, could you explain more?

Comment: The 1-dimensional subspaces of $\Bbb{R}^2$ are spanned by a vector of the $(1,a)$ where $a\in\Bbb{R}$ is some constant. With the exception of the $y$-axis spanned by $(0,1)$. All those subspace are distinct for they correspond to lines through the origin with slope $a$ (resp. ithe vertical line of infinite slope). Replace $\Bbb{R}$ with the field $\Bbb{Z}_p$ everywhere.

Comment: Or, start with the Klein four group for the case $p=2$.

Comment: Eh, I don't get it, but thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that. I made an invalid assumption about your background. Anyway, I endorse citadel's answer, which is pure counting under the assumption that all the elements have order $p$ (which is the case with $C_p\times C_p$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $G$ is cyclic, then there is precisely one subgroup of order $p$.

If $G$ is non-cyclic, then all the $p^2-1$ nontrivial elements have order $p$, and hence each of them lays in one and only one subgroup of order $p$ (these subgroups are pairwise trivially intersecting). So, said $k$ the number of subgroups of order $p$, we get:
$$p^2-1=k(p-1)$$
whence $k=p+1$. All such $G$ are isomorphic to $C_p\times C_p$.

Comment: But in the case $G= \mathbb Z_3$ x $\mathbb Z_3$ the subgroups $<(0,1)>$ and $<(0,2)>$ are equal, they don't intersect only at $\{e\}$.

Comment: @santm, we want to count the *distinct* subgroups, isn't it?

Comment: I thought that even having different representatives they were the same. So in the case $G=\mathbb Z_9$ (cyclic), it has two subgroups of order 3, $<3>$ and $<6>$.

Comment: Explicitly for $p=3$, @santm: $\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_3$ is "a flower" made of $p+1=4$ "petals" and the central "pistil" (the identity $(0,0)$). The first "petal" is $\langle(1,0)\rangle$, the second is $\langle(0,1)\rangle$, the third is $\langle(1,1)\rangle$, and the forth and last is $\langle(1,2)\rangle$.

Comment: Ahh, I got it now. Thank you!!